# The perimeter of the rectangle is $20$, diagonal is $8$ and side is $x$. Show that $x^2-10x+18=0$

Tags: geometry, quadratics

My friends recently took a Maths GCSE. In the paper, they came across a very difficult question which we spent a full half-hour train journey trying to figure out. We didn't manage it, so I've come here hoping you can help us out.

Here is the question:

[image]

The perimeter of the rectangle is 20.
Show that $x^2-10x+18=0$

Sorry for my appalling rectangle drawing skills. Drawing with Paint is like trying to staple an apple to your face. Painful and difficult.

Comment: Is the length of diagonal $8$?

Comment: Glad you asked, Inceptio...I thought it was "s" at first.

Comment: amWhy, Now it looks more like $\delta$.

Comment: @Inceptio Sorry, but like I said, Paint happened. By the way, it is indeed 8

Comment: @imulsion: The same *paint*.

Comment: @Inceptio thanks :)

Comment: Please avoid *subjective* titles. Instead, consider giving your posts informative and objective titles.

Comment: Staple an apple to your face? HAHA!

Comment: Since you have two constraints and two unknowns - $x$ and the length of the other side - (constraints are sum of squares of sides by Pythagoras and sum of sides by perimeter) it is obvious you will get a quadratic. To get the quadratic you have to find the product of the sides from what you already know (Vieta for quadratics - look it up as it will help you in due course with higher degrees. Also "Vieta jumping" is an initially surprising technique which can solve some apparently difficult problems involving only quadratics)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider one triangle formed when diagonal is drawn. Let $x$ be one of the sides, other side will be $10-x$

$(10-x)^2+x^2=k^2$

$10^2+2x^2-20x=k^2$ , Looking at the expression $k$ looks like $8$. So, $36+2x^2-10x=0$

Comment: how does the final equation cancel to $x^2-10x+18$?

Comment: $36+2x^2-10x=2(x^2-10x+18)=0$ You cancel $2$ throughout.

Comment: Thank you! This was such a hard question

Comment: @imulsion: No, it wasn't. You just have to observe things.:)

Comment: i'm not that great at maths or observing things xD

Comment: @Inceptio: That is a subjective thing to say (that the problem is not hard) and is not very constructive for someone who does think it is hard. Really, you could say the same thing that you said about any math problem: you just have to observe things.

Answer (score 3):

Use the Pythagorean theorem. The width of the rectangle is $w=x$, and the length is $2l=20-2x$, therefore $l=10-x$. Therefore the diagonal $8^2=w^2+l^2=x^2+(10-x)^2$. Now expand this and show that it is equal to the quadratic you stated.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Let y be the other side. Then $y^2 + x^2 = 64$ and $2(y+x) = 20$.

Answer (score 1):

Let the side not given be $a$. Since the perimeter is 20, we know that $2x+2a=20$ which we can rearrange to obtain $a=10-x$. By the Pythagorean theorem, $x^2+a^2=8^2=64$. Substituting for $a$, we have $x^2+(10-x)^2=64$ which simplifies to $x^2-10x+18=0$; the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Pythagorean Theorem and simultaneous equations to come up with $x^2 + y^2 = 8^2$
and $2x + 2y = 20$.

Therefore, $x + y = 10$.

x (squared) + (10-x) (squared) = 64

2x(squared) - 20x + 100 = 64

(2x (squared) - 20x + 36)/2 = 0

x - 10x + 18 = 0

Answer (score 0):

Let the height = y.

Therefore we can now create 2 simultaneous equations:-

1) X+y=10 (since perimeter of whole rectangle equals 20, X and y together must equal half ie 10)

2) (8^2)-(x^2)=(y^2) (using pythagrus)

So if we change around the first equation, we can get:- y=10-X, now plugging this into the second equation we get;- (8^2)-(x^2)=(10-X)^2, which is the same as - 64-(x^2)=100-20x+(x^2), which equals (ie, bringing everything on the left hand side over to the right) - 0=36-20x+2(x^2), now divide this whole equation by 2, you get:-

0=18-10x+(x^2),

Which of course when rearranged, is the same as:-

(x^2)-10x+18=0

Answer (score -1):

Name one side $y$.

$2x+2y=20$ therefore $x+y=10$ and $y=10-x$

By the Pythagorean Theorem,

$(10-x)²+x²=8²$ and therefore

$2x²-20x-100=64$,

$2x²-20x+36=0$,

$x²-10x+18=0$